# AWK for filling up rest of the columns with &nbsp in file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm trying to get AWK filling up following text file for "empty" columns".

Basic idea of finding longest line with AWK NF and checking which line has no value on that column. Then adding x times N/A for each empty column.

This example is input space separated, but of course it can be changed easily to any character separated file.

Input can be as:

```
aaa bbb ccc ddd
aaa 
aaa bbb ccc
hhh ppp uuu
www yyy hhh
hhh 111 333 yyy ooo hyy uuuioooy
```

And output where amount of max columns in file is calculated and N/A added to columns that empty.

```
aaa bbb ccc ddd N/A N/A N/A
aaa N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A
aaa bbb ccc N/A N/A N/A N/A
hhh ppp uuu N/A N/A N/A N/A 
www yyy hhh N/A N/A N/A N/A 
hhh 111 333 yyy ooo hyy uuuioooy
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to do it in two steps, first find the widest line:

```
max=$(awk 'max < NF { max = NF } END { print max }' infile)
```

Then use that as input when filling out the other columns:

```
awk -v max=$max '{ for(i=NF+1; i<=max; i++) $i = "N/A"; print }' infile
```

Answer (score 5):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{if(m<NF)m=NF;next}{for(i=NF;i<m;i++)$(i+1)="N/A"}1' tiny.txt tiny.txt
```

Note the input file name specified twice.

Comment: I came to realize your AWK snipped leaves missing one column from the end.

Answer (score 0):

If your file contains field separators for all columns also in lines with missing fields, then there is another nice solution that can also handle situations where the missing fields are within the line and not only at the end of the line.
For example any spreadsheet with empty cells (if using the right separator).

Eg. for a space separated file

```
aaa bbb ccc ddd  ggg
aaa  abb ccc  
www yyy hhh   
www yyy 333 yyy ooo hyy
```

you can use

```
awk -F'[ ]' '{OFS=" ";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i==""){$i="N/A"}};print}' infile.txt
```

or for tab separated:

```
awk -F'\t' '{OFS="\t";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i==""){$i="N/A"}};print}' infile.txt
```

careful with DOS/Windows generated files eg. from Excel, where you need to remove carriage returns:

```
cat infile.txt | tr -d '\r' | awk -F'[ ]' '{OFS=" ";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i==""){$i="N/A"}};print}'
```

Maybe this is not exactly fit for the question, but it might be useful for many users.

Comment: This is a reasonably good and well-written answer (but do a search for the term “UUOC”).  Unfortunately, as you know, it isn’t really an answer to ***this*** question.  We can be flexible about answers for “almost the same question”, but I doubt that anybody who has the problem you’re solving will ever find your answer here under this question about “filling up rest of the columns”. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Furthermore, Unix & Linux Stack Exchange already has nearly 8000 questions about awk, and [SU] and [SO] probably have more.  I expect that there’s another question out there that’s a better match for your answer.  And there is probably an answer to ***that*** question that is equivalent to yours.  You might have better luck focusing on newer questions.